# Ordering rows when there is a tie between several of them

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have a data.frame (corresponding to a leaderboard) like this one:

```
structure(list(PJ = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), V = c(4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1), E = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), D = c(0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), GF = c(182, 
91, 92, 185, 126, 119), GC = c(84, 143, 144, 115, 141, 168), 
    Dif = c(98, -52, -52, 70, -15, -49), Pts = c(12, 6, 6, 6, 
    3, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Player1", "Player2", 
"Player3", "Player4", "Player5", "Player6"))
```

I would like to order the rows according to the number of points `Pts`. This can be done by `df[order(df$Pts, decreasing=T),]`. The issue appears when there is a tie between several players, then, what I want to do is to order the rows according to `Dif`.

How can this be done?

Comment: The [`arrange()` function from the dplyr package](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html) is one potential option, e.g. `library(dplyr); df %>% arrange(Pts, Dif)`

Comment: try `df %>% arrange(desc(Pts), desc(Dif))`

Comment: @KarthikS, exactly what you posted in order to get a decreasing ordination. Thanks to both of you

Comment: decrease is an vector, you can do `d[order(d$Pts, d$Dif, decreasing = c(T, F)), ]` if the ties should be increasing or `d[order(d$Pts, d$Dif, decreasing = c(T, T)), ]`if the ties should be decreasing as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `order` function which you are already using can take multiple arguments, each used sequentially to break ties in the previous one; see [?order](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html)

So you simply have to add `Dif` to you existing call:

```
df[order(df$Pts, df$Dif, decreasing=T),]
```

You can add further terms to break any remaining ties, e.g. Player2 and Player3 who have identical Pts and Dif.

If you want to specify which direction each argument should be ordered by (increasing or decreasing), you can either specify the `decreasing` argument as a vector, as in @r.user.05apr's comment, or my preferred lazy solution of adding `-` to any term that should be ordered in a decreasing direction

```
df[order(-df$Pts, df$Dif),]
```

(this will order by Pts *decreasing* and Dif *increasing*; it won't work if e.g. one of the ordering columns is character)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sqldf` or `dplyr` library

```
library (sqldf)

sqldf('select *
       from "df"
       order by "Pts" desc, "Dif" desc ')
```

Output

```
PJ V E D  GF  GC Dif Pts
1  4 4 0 0 182  84  98  12
2  4 2 0 2 185 115  70   6
3  4 2 0 2  91 143 -52   6
4  4 2 0 2  92 144 -52   6
5  4 1 0 3 126 141 -15   3
6  4 1 0 3 119 168 -49   3
```